# no matching provisioning profiles found in xcode 6

Tags: iphone, xcode6

I am getting `No matching provisioning profiles found for "My application"` message when I try to make `Ad Hoc Distribution` of application using xcode 6. I tried all the possible solution but they are not working. please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, you need to create a new Distribution profile, specific for Ad Hoc Deployment. This can be found in the classic member center, but it is a new type of certificate.

You can then select which devices can be used to test the app as ou would do with a developer profile.

And the newly created certificate will be available when you export your package from the Organizer the usual way.

Alternatively you can use the TestFlight solution provided by Apple with iOS 8 to enable your user to have access to prerelease.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

When I switched from Xcode 5 to Xcode 6,  I had to download the provisioning profiles again and drop them onto the Xcode 6 app icon.

Then things usually worked normally.

Comment: That did it for me. I've been so used to dropping profiles into the iPhone Configuration Utility.

Answer (score 0):

I got it with revoking developer AND distribution certificates and regenerating ALL profiles/certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so what I did was I deleted my project, and luckily I had a back up of before I tried adding those provision files and then I loaded up that backup and when I tried it worked, another approach to this is to create a new Xcode project and import and replace the files from the other project that's finished, for me either way works.